# What does mean the fact of washing the feet of the disciple by Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, disciple, footwashing

There was the fact of washing the feet of the disciples by Jesus. What does it mean ?

Comment: A Similar question like this has already been closed: [Why did Jesus wash his disciples' feet?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48733/why-did-jesus-wash-his-disciples-feet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jesus explained this himself to his disciples:

> When he had finished washing their feet, he put on his clothes and returned to his place. “Do you understand what I have done for you?” he asked them. “You call me ‘Teacher’ and ‘Lord,’ and rightly so, for that is what I am. Now that I, your Lord and Teacher, have washed your feet, you also should wash one another’s feet. I have set you an example that you should do as I have done for you. Very truly I tell you, no servant is greater than his master, nor is a messenger greater than the one who sent him. Now that you know these things, you will be blessed if you do them.

John 13:12-17, New International Version

The disciples were to hold themselves as servants of one another. Similarly, all Christians should do the same.